# LayoutManager boundingRectForGlyphRange for multiline texts

Tags: ios, objective-c, layout-manager

I have a text, which is displayed on a screen exactly like that:

```
#first SomePersonFirstName
SomePersonLastName #secondTag
```

In my application I keep information about 3 tags for this text together with their range, which are:

1. #first
2. SomePersonFirstName SomePersonLastName
3. #secondTag

Now after I display it to user I want to detect which one was clicked, so I iterate through all informations I have, get a `boundingRectForGlyphRange` for each of them, and check if this rect contains a point where it was clicked.

Everything works in general, but I got a strange situation which breaks my idea about how I do it.
Problem is that bounding rects overlaps for those tags.

[image]

Because person tag was splitted into 2 lines, bound rects starts at 0,0 and covers #first bounding rect.

Problem is that when you click on this conflicted areas, there is no way to figure out which one was clicked.

I actually have no idea how to approach that. Is there any other way to detect bounding rect but that will not actually bound to empty areas, that will cover just text itself ?

EDIT

The code I'm using:

```
- (CGRect)boundingRectForCharacterRange:(NSRange)range
{
    NSTextStorage *textStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithAttributedString:self.labelTitle.attributedText];
    NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = [[NSLayoutManager alloc] init];
    [textStorage addLayoutManager:layoutManager];
    NSTextContainer *textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeMake(self.labelTitle.bounds.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
    textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0;
    textContainer.lineBreakMode = self.labelTitle.lineBreakMode;
    [layoutManager addTextContainer:textContainer];

    NSRange glyphRange;
    [layoutManager characterRangeForGlyphRange:range actualGlyphRange:&glyphRange];
    return [layoutManager boundingRectForGlyphRange:glyphRange inTextContainer:textContainer];
}

-(void)tapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)recognizer.view;
    CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:label];

    CommentTag* selectedCommentTag = nil;
    for (CommentTag* commentTag in self.comment.tags)
    {
        CGRect commentRect = [self boundingRectForCharacterRange:[commentTag tagRange]];
        if(CGRectContainsPoint(commentRect, location))
        {
            if(selectedCommentTag == nil)
            {
                selectedCommentTag = commentTag;
            }
            else
            {
                if(selectedCommentTag.offset > commentTag.offset)
                {
                    selectedCommentTag = commentTag;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(selectedCommentTag)
    {
        if([selectedCommentTag.type isEqualToString:COMMENTTAG_TYPE_TAG])
        {
            NSLog(@"%@", [selectedCommentTag value]);
        }
    }
}
```

Here I just take the first tag to the left, but that doesn't solve a problem of #secondTag from my example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two (three) instances when two bounding rects can overlap:

1. The two ranges overlap index values.
2. One of the bounding rects occupies multiple lines.
3. Both of the bounding rects occupy multiple lines.

For (1), you're just going to have to make your own set of rules for when you accept a click on a common glyph.

For (2), always prefer touches on the range that spans only one line -- you can tell this by comparing the rect height.

For (3), you'll have to iterate through the lines.

Alternatively, have you considered the opposite method?

```
NSRange characterRange = [layoutManager glyphRangeForBoundingRect:CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, 1, 1) inTextContainer:container];
if (NSLocationInRange(characterRange.location, firstRange) {
  // ...
} else if (NSLocationInRange(characterRange.location, secondRange) {
  // ...
} // etc...
```

By converting your touch point to a `CGRect` with size `1x1`, you're able to get your `layoutManager` to provide you an `NSRange` of length `1` representing the single glyph at your touch point. Using this `NSRange`'s `location`, you can compare to your `NSRange` list and see which one you hit. Using your source:

```
- (NSUInteger)glyphIndexForPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    NSTextStorage *textStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithAttributedString:self.labelTitle.attributedText];
    NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = [[NSLayoutManager alloc] init];
    [textStorage addLayoutManager:layoutManager];
    NSTextContainer *textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeMake(self.labelTitle.bounds.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
    textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0;
    textContainer.lineBreakMode = self.labelTitle.lineBreakMode;
    [layoutManager addTextContainer:textContainer];
    return [layoutManager glyphIndexForPoint:point inTextContainer:textContainer];;
}

-(void)tapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)recognizer.view;
    CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:label];
    NSUInteger glyphIndex = [self glyphIndexForPoint:location];

    CommentTag* selectedCommentTag = nil;
    for (CommentTag* commentTag in self.comment.tags)
    {
        if (NSLocationInRange(glyphIndex, [commentTag tagRange]))
        {
            NSLog(@"%@", commentTag); //selected tag
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I especially like the idea to actually iterate through all lines - I think I will just do that for all cases - that should cover 2,3 in the same time probably. 1st one doesn't happen on my app since I generate those ranges during edit mode which won't allow them to overlap. Do you think that going through all words by splitting them up with space and check if point belongs to a word separately ? Sounds about right...

Comment: I didn't get the last idea with opposite method, can you explain more ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Idea is good but unfortunately I'm getting whole lines from your proposal. For {15, 12.5} I get first line: {0, 34}
for point {71, 25.5} I get second line range {34, 19}. Looks like space is treated as fall of glyph

Comment: Interesting. Well, that should still really help you solve it. Now that you know the range of the line you touched, you should be able to determine which `[commentTag tagRange]` you've selected.

Comment: Yeah it helped I have a solution better than one you proposed. I will propose edit for your post, so other can have ready to use soliton

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski did you ever manage to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Yes solution from answer above works well. Only thing I've added is "textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = self.labelText.numberOfLines;"